# Counting the number of unique nodes in XML using XQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

```
<Bookstore>
<Book ISBN="ISBN-0-13-035300-0" Price="65" Edition="2nd">
<Title>A First Course in Database Systems</Title>
<Authors>
<Author>
<First_Name>Jeffrey</First_Name>
<Last_Name>Ullman</Last_Name>
</Author>
<Author>
<First_Name>Jennifer</First_Name>
<Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name>
</Author>
</Authors>
</Book>
<Book ISBN="ISBN-0-13-031995-3" Price="75">
<Title>Database Systems: The Complete Book</Title>
<Authors>
<Author>
<First_Name>Hector</First_Name>
<Last_Name>Garcia-Molina</Last_Name>
</Author>
<Author>
<First_Name>Jeffrey</First_Name>
<Last_Name>Ullman</Last_Name>
</Author>
<Author>
<First_Name>Jennifer</First_Name>
<Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name>
</Author>
</Authors>
<Remark>
Amazon.com says: Buy this book bundled with "A First Course,"
it’s a great deal!
</Remark>
</Book>
</Bookstore>
```

Using the above XML I would like to select authors which have authored 'A First Course In Database Systems' AND have written another book

```
for $b in /Bookstore/Book
let $a := $b/Authors/Author
let $t := $b/Title
where $t = "Database Systems: The Complete Book" and count($a)>1
return $a
```

But this returns all the authors because I think it is just counting the number of authors for that book. I want to count the number of time each unique author appears in total as I think this is the approach to take.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

That can be expressed in pure XPath as

```
/Bookstore/Book[Title = 'A First Course in Database Systems']/Authors/Author[. = /Bookstore/Book[Title != 'A First Course in Database Systems']/Authors/Author]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to do it with xquery, try:

```
let 
$Book := $store//Book, 
$opus := "A First Course in Database Systems",
$authors := $Book[Title=$opus]/Authors/Author,
$others := $Book[Title!=$opus]/Authors/Author
```

Pre-edit:

```
for 
$author in $authors, 
$other in $others
where $author = $other
return $author
```

Edited:

```
for $author in $authors
where $author = $others
return $author
```

I left the "before" and "after" in place so that the exchange of of comments with Martin Honnen, below, continue to make sense for future viewers.

Comment: This will return duplicates if one `Author` has written more than one "other" book. So with a `for .. return` you might be better off to return the `$author`.

Comment: Thinking about it again, my rewrite doesn't help as the second `$other in $others` will continue to have the effect of adding duplicates, even if returning `$author`. I think it is better to remove that second `in` clause completely and go with `for $author in $authors where $author = $others return $author`

Comment: @MartinHonnen I run your suggestion and it works, but before I edit the answer again to reflect it, a preliminary question (unless you tell me I should post it as a separate question): how is it possible for `$author = $others` to be `true` when `count($others)` is `4` while `count($author)` is obviously `1`? I thought you need to compare each `$author` to each member of `$others` (hence, the `for $other in $others`, but it seems unnecessary. So why is that the case?

Comment: In XPath and that way XQuery and XSLT the general comparison operators like `=` give true as long as at least one item on the left compares to at least one item on the right.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Wow! That's news to me - I don't recall running into this observation before. And, I might add, it's a bit counter-intuitive: `[a,b,c]=[c,d,e]` is true just because they share `c`? I guess I'll have to live with it. In any case, I'll incorporate it into an edit to the answer.

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-general-comparisons for the details. Your example syntax with e.g. `[a,b,c]` is a bit confusing but if you use e.g. `('a', 'b', 'c')`, i.e. sequences of values then, yes, `('a', 'b', 'c') = ('c', 'd', 'e')` because both sequences contain `c`.